# Past tense and "rather than"

Tags: past-tense, infinitives, gerunds

I found myself with a sentence like this, using "accept" in the infinitive form after "rather than":

> They left the club, rather than accept the terms.

But I'm unsure of its grammatical soundness. Conjugating the verb "accept" just sounds wrong:

> They left the club, rather than accepted the terms.

The gerund sounds right, but I'm not sure why:

> They left the club, rather than accepting the terms.

What is the grammatically correct way of phrasing this sort of sentence, and why?

> [SUBJECT] [PAST_ACTION_1], rather than [PAST_ACTION_2]

Answer (score 8):

As you've noted, *rather than* is a bit of a strange beast. I can't offer a complete analysis, but it isn't grammatical to put a finite verb after *than* in the past tense. Rather, it must be either the uninflected base form or the present participle. The choice between them is partially controlled by the tense of the main verb.

> He left rather than watch the movie.
>
> ? He left rather than watching the movie. (Sounds wrong to me)
>
> *He left rather than watched the movie. (Always wrong)

From [this article](http://www.englishrules.com/writing/2005/rather-than-and-instead-of/), I offer the following quote from the *American Heritage Book of English Usage*:

> The phrase *rather than* consists of an
> adverb and a conjunction and often
> means “and not,” as in *I decided to
> skip lunch rather than eat in the
> cafeteria again*. It is grammatically
> similar to sooner than in that it is
> used with a “bare” infinitive—an
> infinitive minus *to*: *I would stay here
> and eat flies sooner than go with
> them*.
>
> *Rather than* can also be used with
> nouns as a compound preposition
> meaning “instead of”: *I bought a
> mountain bike rather than a ten-speed*.
> But some people object to this use,
> insisting that *than* should be used
> only as a conjunction. They therefore
> object to constructions in which
> *rather than* is followed by a gerund,
> as in *Rather than buying a new car, I
> kept my old one*. [Editor's note: these people are clearly insane. *rather than* + gerund is just fine, as is *rather than* + noun phrase.]
>
> In some cases, however, *rather than*
> can only be followed by a gerund and
> not by a bare infinitive. If the main
> verb of the sentence has a form that
> does not allow parallel treatment of
> the verb following *rather than*, you
> cannot use a bare infinitive, and you
> must use a gerund. This is often the
> case when the main verb is in a past
> tense or has a participle. Thus, you
> must say *The results of the study,
> rather than ending (not end or ended)
> the controversy, only added to it*. If
> the main verb was in the present tense
> (*add*), you could use the bare
> infinitive *end*.
>
> Curiously, when the *rather than*
> construction follows the main verb, it
> can use other verb forms besides the
> bare infinitive. Thus you can say *The
> results of the study added to the
> controversy rather than ended it*.
>
> The overriding concern in all of this
> should be to avoid faulty parallels,
> as in sentences like *Rather than buy a
> new car, I have kept my old one* and
> *Rather than take a cab, she is going
> on foot*.

Comment: Your first paragraph seems to contradict your quotation: perhaps you could specify a bit in which circumstances the past tense is not grammatical. Cf. *Curiously, when the "rather than" construction follows the main verb, it can use other verb forms besides the bare infinitive. Thus you can say **The results of the study added to the controversy rather than ended it.*** My guess would be that it is possible as long as both verbs share all (most? some?) of their complements.

Comment: @Cerberus The difference is that a subordinate clause exists in the example at the top marked ungrammatical, while the quoted text is puzzling over a sentence that contains no subordinate clause. "The results of the study added to the controversy rather than ended it" is a single clause, while *"He left rather than watched the movie" contains the subclause *"rather than watched the movie". It has to do with the verb phrase structures: v[added to the controversy rather than ended it] is a complete phrase, while in the ungrammatical case v[left] and v[watched the movie] are separate phrases.

Comment: @Cerberus Verb tense is handled differently in subordinate clauses than main clauses, so the existence of a containing subordinate clause is the controlling factor in whether full tense expression is grammatical, or whether tense is constrained to the bare indefinite or gerund.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie: Hmm I don't understand. Both sentences contain subordinate clauses, which are the *than*-clauses; in neither sentence is there another subordinate clause. *Rather than ended it* is as much a subordinate clause as is *watched the movie*.

Comment: @Cerberus: I think the idea is that in the *study* sentence "rather than" is acting as a conjunction (parallel to *The results of the study added to the controversy **and** ended it*, or *... **or** ended it*), and hence that sentence has two main clauses (co-ordinated, with elision in the second). I think the meaning of *rather than* is slightly different in the two usages, but I can't quite put my finger on how at the moment... I may give it some thought and see if I can explain what I'm thinking better later :)

Comment: Is such a lengthy quoted excerpt in the Answer content truly necessary? @JSBngs own content is  quite good, along with the three examples  provided as support. May I suggest considering removal of some part of the extensive cited quotation that follows?

Comment: *"He leaves rather than watches the movie"* sounds to me like you're pointing out the fact of his leaving to someone who might have thought otherwise. The more common *He leaves rather than watch the movie* implies **he** made a choice. Choice of verb form seems to radically change the meaning of *"rather than".*

Answer (score 2):

This is a slithery beast indeed.

It seems that *rather than* has two usages:

The first is comparable to *and not*:

> You should stay overnight rather than drive home in the rain.

The second is comparable to *instead of*, used to indicate a preference between two or more options:

> I'd like chicken rather than fish.
>
> I think I'll leave rather than enter the club.
>
> He rejected rather than accepted the terms.

The example at hand, where a choice was made to not accept terms and therefore leave a club seems to be the first usage. You're not talking about a choice of options here, you're talking about what you *did not do*. What did you do? You left the club. What did you not do? You did not accept the terms.

> He chose to leave the club and not accept the terms. He chose to leave the club **rather than** accept the terms.

Note the presence of the particle *to* seems to help here. I'm not convinced that '*He left the club rather than ...'* is valid regardless of what follows. If this was a real-life problem at the very least I'd suggest taking out *than* and re-phrasing:

> He did not accept the terms, but rather left the club.

Comment: I'm not convinced your *and not* and *instead of* meanings are really any different. Per my comment to JSBngs, *"He leaves rather than watches the movie"* and *"He leaves rather than watch the movie"* are very different meanings. In the first, the speaker is simply clarifying that one thing is happening, not another. In the second, we're being told about the *choice* someone makes, and the other option they've rejected.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, I certainly don't claim to be authorative on this. I suppose by 'instead of' I am talking about a choice of options such as whether to eat fish or chicken. The question is what to eat. The options are related. With 'and not' it's a _decision_ whether to eat chicken or go for a walk - it's not a question of what to eat but whether to eat. Fine point perhaps but I think there are two distinct usages for 'rather than'.