# parallel structure - in a "rather than" structure

Tags: syntactic-analysis, correlative-conjunctions

I am doing some researches to understand clearly the usage of *rather than*. However I found myself even more confused by some peripheral stuff.

In this post ([Past tense and "rather than"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/22534/past-tense-and-rather-than)), the American Heritage dictionary was being quoted to illustrate the proper usage of *rather than*.  It is stated that, in some cases, *rather than* can only be followed by a gerund. It gave as an example this sentence:

> "The result of the study, rather than **ending** the controversy, only added to it".

It states that if *end* or *ended* had been used, the sentence would be wrong because "...the main verb has a form which would not allow parallel treatment of the verb following *rather than*."

I am confused by this statement. Could someone explain to me, what does "the main verb has a form which would not allow parallel treatment" in this context mean?

By the way, I am still very confused about the usage of *rather than*, can anyone point me to a comprehensive source so that I could really grasp the idea?

Comment: possible duplicate of [\[clause in simple tense\], rather than \[verb in -ing form\]](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138800/clause-in-simple-tense-rather-than-verb-in-ing-form) {see esp Neil Coffey's answer}

Comment: I have also read the post you cited here. However, I cannot derive satisfactory answer from Neil's answer, especially in relation to the particular statement that I am concerned about. Or did I overlook something? (see Marius Hancu's comment below. It partly demonstrates my confusion)

Comment: "The result of the study actually added to rather than ended the controversy." is the only acceptable choice out of _end / to end / ending / ended_ with this word ordering, in my opinion. "The result of the study, rather than ending the controversy, only added to it." is again, I'd say, the only choice. **BUT**  "The result of the study added to the controversy rather than ending/ended it." both sound acceptable. // The AHD needs to explain itself better. But a research paper would probably be required to better explain these idiosyncratic constructions.

Answer (score 2):

I cannot explain it in grammatical terms but perhaps I can state it in logical terms. The "main verb" in this case is "added". It's past tense because the result of the study did in fact add to the controversy. Therefore the "parallel treatment" for the hypothetical is not possible because the hypothetical did not occur and cannot be expressed in the past tense. The gerund "ending" allows for the hypothetical.

Comment: How about using the bare infinitive: "The result of the study, rather than _end_ the controversy, only added to it." Can you explain why this wouldn't be correct? Thanks.

Comment: @Marius I think it's back to Neil Coffey's 'there's a strong affinity for the  -_ing_ form after _rather than_' [paraphrasing]. Not that this explains **why**, of course.

Comment: I want to say that a "rather than" formulation where one side of the comparison has occurred and the other side is a hypothetical calls for the accusative rather than a functional verb on the hypothetical side.

Comment: @Marius: if you used the bare infinitive in the OP's sentence, it would not be a past tense. That is, you would say *"The result of the study, rather than end the controversy, will only add to it",* for a future event; and *"The result of the study, rather than ending the controversy, only added to it"*, for a past event.

Comment: @Peter Shor: It is known that the infinitive and the ing-forms/participle/gerund are all non-finite forms. Such forms do not express a time by themselves. Their meaning is set according to the context. How could then __end__ change the time expressed by the subordinate? That time is dictated by the finite verb in the main, the indicative __added__.

Comment: @Peter Shor Are you saying that this sentence given by Collins Cobuild is wrong? "Rather than __break__ her appointment and __disappoint me__, Katie again __took__ the car."

Comment: @Peter Shor Also, are you saying that this sentence given by Swan as model is wrong? "Rather than __wait__ any more, I __decided__ to go home by taxi."

Comment: @Peter Shor "It __was__ an audience of at least a couple of thousand who __came__ to hear music rather than __go__ to the beach." is from Leech, Geoffrey and Svartvik, Jan: A Communicative Grammar of English, Third Edition. Longman 2002 (Sections 715 and 310). Is this a wrong sentence? All these sentences are using simple past in the main, and bare infinitive after "rather than," in the subordinate.

Comment: @Marius: certainly the last two (Swan and Longman) sound fine. I don't know what the difference is; let me think about it. I think it might be volition, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 2):

This is what is mentioned in this famous grammar, which in turns quotes a great novelist:

> ... we have come to feel that the simple infinitive is to be used with
>   rather ...:
>
> '*Rather than* ***disturb*** him she ***went*** for a light-box and his
>   cigar-case to his bedroom' (Thackeray, Pendennis, I, Ch. XVIII)
>
> **George Curme, A Grammar of the English Language**, Vol II, Syntax, 49 4 E, p. 480

which represents another clear example of using *rather than* with the **bare infinitive** in a context in which the main sentence uses a **simple past** verb.

May I suggest that those interested should read these threads elsewhere, which make reference to the recommendations of **Quirk, Swan**,  **Leech and Svartvik**, and **Collins Cobuild Dictionary** on the matter of **"rather than"**:

["rather than" and "instead of"](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/1141082733)

[Subjunctive?](http://thegrammarexchange.infopop.cc/eve/forums/a/tpc/f/340600179/m/43710788?r=15010329#15010329)

In particular, in these sources there seems to be much less strictness related to the use of the **bare infinitive** with the "rather than" construct than what I've seen in the references in the OP here.